# Facebook desktop app (on browser) - login without hosting on a webserver

Tags: facebook, authentication, desktop-application

I am trying to develop a Facebook desktop app that runs on a browser (but not on a webserver). So strictly speaking, I am running a standalone webpage that is not in any domain. I am in need to find a suitable login solution for this.

Currently, Facebook authentication has to be redirected to another URI - the problem for me is that I am unable to get the access token from this redirected page (dialog/poup) because of cross-domain access issues. Is there a way across it?

Also, since I am running the page on a filepath (c:/wamp/www/facebook.html) rather than on a webserver, the "auth.login" events are not fired after authentication is done in the dialog. Is this expected behaviour as well?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use local web server and server it from http://localhost... There is planty of lightweight one for Windows (Abyss) as well as Unix (thttpd).

EDIT: It seems it is not possible using file:// urls. I tried this page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function fbLogin() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
      alert("Access token is: "+window.location.hash);
    } else {
      window.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        + "client_id=54715426813&redirect_uri=file:///D:/Herby/Desktop/page.html&response_type=token";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="fbLogin();">
</body>
</html>
```

and oath dialog said

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.
```

which means, you must fill in the file:/// type url in you app config. I tried that, but it said me the protocol used must be http or https. So, bye-bye to facebook on file://

The only possibility for true desktop apps is to include web control that uses true http urls and somehow (through tiny embedded server or by some kind of hook and mocking) is able to use such an URL (or, as was pointed in other answer, you can use no redirection url and get redirected to default facebook result page). But that is not something you can do in a browser only.

Comment: Thanks, but the requirements are not to use any webserver at all. If I had wanted to use one, it would be pretty simple, wouldn't it?

Comment: You do not need to use dialog/popus at all. I don't know what problems are facebook putting along the way, but using client-side flow (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) it seems pretty easy to get the access token, if url=file://... works. I did not try, though. No cross-domain issues should play a role here, you get an access token in the fragment part of the url.

Comment: herby, thanks. I have gone through the documentation and I am trying the same client-side workflow. I am not sure what you mean by "do not need to use dialog/popups at all. What other options do I have? The client side workflow seems to mandate using the OAuth dialog. Or am I missing something? If I do open a dialog/popup, it is in another domain and I cannot control from my opener

Comment: Client-side flow does not use dialog nor popup, but normal click or the `window.location=`, that is, it can do it in a full page. So no concerns about "inter-window cross-domain communication". It then redirects to your page giving an access token in fragment of the url. I just don't know if it accepts file:/// urls for redirection (and if it is possible to redirect to file:/// urls at all, there may be cross-domain issue as well).

Comment: I cannot find a way to make it work with window.location= method. I tried it with an iframe but the iframe doesn't even load. Could you point me to an example where it has been done using the method you describe? I would mark this as an answer if you give me an example that works.

Comment: I know of no concrete example. `window.location=` should work to get you to oauth dialog itself. What is the problem you are getting: no auth dialog at all or bad behaviour after you accept it? Are you going to login automatically after loading the page or upon the click (in that case you can put url of oauth dialog simply in the href)?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on FB Auth: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

If your app is able to read iframe URLs (such as an AIR based app) then you can rely on using the Desktop App Auth Flow and reading the credentials from the response URL that Facebook hosts: `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html#access_token=...`

Comment: Facebook does not allow iframe for OAuth dialog. The requirement is to run it in a regular browser - not an embedded one that comes with Adobe AIR or .NET environment. Is there a way one can turn off cross-domain checks in a browser ?

Comment: It doesn't allow it but you can still do it, especially in AIR. I don't think it's wise to ask each user to turn off xdomain security.

Comment: Ahmed, thanks. But as I have pointed out earlier, I am bound to specific requirements that demand that I try to make it work in regular browser like Chrome/Firefox. I am not sure if its possible but thats what I am trying to check now

Comment: Unfortunately without it being a proper app or taking advantage of extensions, such as a Chrome extension, reading cross-domain is going be near impossible.

Comment: Would you know a chrome extension that can enable cross-domain access? I can use it for my testing and see what other options are available

Comment: Check out TweetDeck, they redirect you back to their web server and get the access key off that; that may be a solution?